# Promise array returns empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, promise

With the help of this site I've created two functions from where a combined array should return with some data in it. Still learning jquery + promises so an answer with some explaination is much appreciated.

I eventually want to show a delivery date of some product variants with the latest/last delivery date if there are multiple products in the cart.

The idea is that there's an array A created with some products in it. Next I get some JSON data from products in this array A. Third there's a new array B created with matching data from the getJson function and this one flattened/merged into a single array with multiple objects (depending on the amount of matching products offcourse. Eventually this array B is send to another function that sets the delivery time for the client in the cart.

Let's say there are two products in the cart, like so:

```
<div class="prod" data-pid="41853029" data-vid="79380299" data-qty="1">....<div>
<div class="prod" data-pid="41853029" data-vid="79380296" data-qty="3">....<div>
```

I then create an array with the data from these two products, like so:

```
function getAllItems() {    
  var promiseArray = $('.prod').map(function() {    
    var item = {
      id: $(this).data('pid'),
      amt: $(this).data('qty'),
      vid: $(this).data('vid'),
      url: 'https://link-to-supplier/stock/'+$(this).data('pid')+'?secret=secret&quantity='+$(this).data('qty')
    };
    // return promise from getItemData()

    /* console.log(getItemData(item)) returns =>
Object { id: 41853029, amt: 1, vid: 79380299, url: "correct link" }
Object { state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), promise: promise(), pipe: then(), done: add(), fail: add(), progress: add() }
Object { id: 41853029, amt: 1, vid: 79380299, url: "correct link" }
Object { id: 41853029, amt: 3, vid: 79380296, url: "correct link" }
Object { state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), promise: promise(), pipe: then(), done: add(), fail: add(), progress: add()}
Object { id: 41853029, amt: 3, vid: 79380296, url: "correct link" }
*/


    return getItemData(item);
  }).get();

/* console.log(promiseArray) returns =>
(2) […]
​0: Object { state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), … }
​1: Object { state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), … }
*/

  // return promise
  return Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(res){

  // flatten all the sub arrays produced in getItemData()
  return [].concat.apply([], res)

  })
}
```

The array created in this function goes to another function `getItemData()` that should return a new array with matching data from a getJSON call, like so:

```
function getItemData(item) {
/* console.log(item) returns =>
{
  "id": 41853029,
  "amt": 1,
  "vid": 79380299,
  "url": "correct link"
} etc...
*/

  // return single item request promise
  return $.getJSON(item.url).then(function(data) {
    // filter and map the response data required
    return Object.values(data.variants).filter(function(variant) {
      variant.id == item.vid
    }).map(function(variant) {
      return {
        id: variant.id,
        dt: Number(variant.deliveryTimeInDays),
        dtt: variant.deliveryTime,
        co: variant.cutOffTime,
        sid: variant.supplier_id
      }    
    });
  });
}
```

Json data:

```
{
  "id": 41853029,
  "variants": {
    "79380290": {
      "id": 79380290,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "no",
      "levelLocal": 0,
      "levelSupplier": 0,
      "deliveryTime": "out of stock",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": -1
    },
    "79380293": {
      "id": 79380293,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "no",
      "levelLocal": 0,
      "levelSupplier": 0,
      "deliveryTime": "out of stock",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": -1
    },
    "79380296": {
      "id": 79380296,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "supplier",
      "levelLocal": 1,
      "levelSupplier": 250,
      "deliveryTime": "Three days",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": 3
    },
    "79380299": {
      "id": 79380299,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "supplier",
      "levelLocal": 2,
      "levelSupplier": 250,
      "deliveryTime": "One day",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Next when I call the function and do a console.log(res) it returns an empty array.

```
getAllItems().then(function(res){
   // all requests have completed and res is combined results
   console.log(res);
}).catch(function(){
   console.log("One of the requests failed")
});
```

​

I just can't figure out why! I'm completely stuck :(

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: for Promise.all() are you using bluebird promise or native promise? because bluebird's promise.all does not return the resolved values.

Comment: I can't see it, but... seems like a good time for some debugging. Either scatter some breakpoints and inspect the interim results, or scatter some console.logs to pinpoint where you're not getting what you're expecting. Is `promiseArray` constructed correctly? Is your filtering overzealous or just right? How about the `res` just before concat?

Comment: Kind of a lot of code. When you debug where does it actually break?  I'd add more logging to check that everything works up till the last step.

Comment: @AZ_: It's a native promise

Comment: @AZ_ The [docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) (and I believe my past Bluebird experience) contradict that... if you found it not to do it, it would be a major bug for Bluebird, and you should report the circumstances.

Comment: @Amadan: I tried this offcourse. Like I said I'm still learning jquery. What I did now is `return Promise.all([promiseArray]).then(function(res){` so added `[]` around the promiseArray. This returns the array with two objects in it. Only the objects show `state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), …` this is a correct result then, right? Sorry if this is a dumb question :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you did, as `[promiseArray]` can't have two elements...

Comment: @Amadan: When I do a `console.log(res)` in my last part of code `getAllItems().then(function(res){`it now shows an array with two objects in it (was first empty as er my question) when I wrap `[promiseArray]`. Only in console.log those two objects show `state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), …` instead of the actual data created in `getItemData`. So my question was is this a correct response or should these objects show the actual data? I'll update my answer quickly!

Comment: The `.get();` is the most suspicious to me. It looks like you are filling `promiseArray` with the results of `.get()` calls. Is that normal?

Comment: No, you got two promises, because of the wrappage. `Promise.all` is not recursive: it will execute the promises in an array, but not promises in an array of arrays. By wrapping `promiseArray` in an additional layer, you basically deactivated them, which is why your console.log is printing them.

Comment: @Evert: jQuery's map has weird semantics in that it wraps whatever result it has into a jQuery object; `.get()` will extract it into a regular array.

Comment: @Amadan: I've added some console.log output to the question. It seems to me that the problem is that `promiseArray`. However I can't see what should be wrong then! Do you have any suggestions perhaps?